# NSXMLParser problem in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

in my app i am using the NSXML parser to fetch data from a network database. here i need to get around 3000 files and more.

my problem is i am getting data's around 1000 files and after that my app gets crashed. Why this happens. Is this because of memory leaks problem or anything else. Please help me friends...

Comment: run the application with Leaks instrument. You can view how much memory the application is taking, and if there are any leaks. You should also receive some memory warnings if memory leaks are the source of the crash. Otherwise see where the app crashes (in Debug) and hope you can find the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly It is because of the memory leaks.  You have to use.

```
NSData * dataXml = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataXml];
[dataXml release];
instead of

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: thanx for your answer, but it works on 4G, but not in 3G and 3Gs.how can get in those mobiles.....

Comment: what happens if you use this in 3G or 3GS? is the application is crashing?

Comment: I think this is not compatible with 3G and 3GS.. you can use aqxmlparser or libxml paraser for this https://github.com/mfazekas/aqxmlparser